# Displaying Admob ads\LocalStorage corruption

Tags: cordova, local-storage, admob, ads

First post and I appreciate there are numerous posts on this topic which I have searched for answers.

I am developing an android app using JQM (1.2), Cordova (2.2), Admob (6.2.1) and my ads do not appear.

```java
    public class cordovaExample extends DroidGap 
    {       
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private AdView adView;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {           //      
                    doAdMob();
                }
            }, 5000);         
     }

     private void doAdMob() 
     {
            // Create the adView           
            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "MYCODE");           
            LinearLayout layout = super.root;
            layout.addView(adView);
            layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
            adView.loadAd(request);   
     }               
}
```

Here is an extract from my logcat:

```
12-17 14:07:06.424: I/Ads(24745): Refreshing ad.
12-17 14:07:06.454: I/Ads(24745): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":2,"session_id":"11970596199473559413","seq_num":"3","slotname":"a150bd20d174dce","u_w":360,"msid":"org.apache.cordova.example","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.org.apache.cordova.example","hl":"en","smart_w":"full","gnt":15,"carrier":"23430","u_audio":1,"u_sd":1.5,"mv":"8016010.com.android.vending","isu":"82D3E2C68BC8ABDE44C1EA123E7289AA","cipa":1,"format":"360x50_mb","oar":2,"smart_h":"auto","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":888,"x":0,"width":540},"u_h":592,"bas_on":0,"ptime":120733});</script></head><body></body></html>
12-17 14:07:06.484: I/Ads(24745): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=2&session_id=11970596199473559413&seq_num=3&u_w=360&msid=org.apache.cordova.example&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.org.apache.cordova.example&hl=en&smart_w=full&gnt=15&carrier=23430&u_audio=1&u_sd=1.5&mv=8016010.com.android.vending&isu=82D3E2C68BC8ABDE44C1EA123E7289AA&cipa=1&format=360x50_mb&oar=2&smart_h=auto&u_h=592&bas_on=0&ptime=120733&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a150bd20d174dce&askip=2&gsb=4g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=41" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
12-17 14:07:06.484: I/Ads(24745): Request scenario: Offline with no buffered ads.
12-17 14:07:06.484: I/Ads(24745): Network is unavailable.  Aborting ad request.
12-17 14:07:06.484: I/Ads(24745): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
12-17 14:08:56.894: I/Ads(25453): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("82D3E2C68BC8ABDE44C1EA123E7289AA");
12-17 14:08:56.954: I/Ads(25453): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"8715359451090924487","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a150bd20d174dce","u_w":360,"msid":"org.apache.cordova.example","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.org.apache.cordova.example","hl":"en","smart_w":"full","gnt":15,"carrier":"23430","u_audio":1,"u_sd":1.5,"mv":"8016010.com.android.vending","isu":"82D3E2C68BC8ABDE44C1EA123E7289AA","cipa":1,"format":"360x50_mb","oar":0,"smart_h":"auto","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":888,"x":0,"width":540},"u_h":592,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
12-17 14:08:57.184: I/Ads(25453): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=8715359451090924487&seq_num=1&u_w=360&msid=org.apache.cordova.example&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.org.apache.cordova.example&hl=en&smart_w=full&gnt=15&carrier=23430&u_audio=1&u_sd=1.5&mv=8016010.com.android.vending&isu=82D3E2C68BC8ABDE44C1EA123E7289AA&cipa=1&format=360x50_mb&oar=0&smart_h=auto&u_h=592&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a150bd20d174dce&gsb=4g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=41" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
12-17 14:08:57.184: I/Ads(25453): Request scenario: Offline with no buffered ads.
12-17 14:08:57.184: I/Ads(25453): Network is unavailable.  Aborting ad request.
12-17 14:08:57.194: I/Ads(25453): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

I think it maybe a problem with my layout as the adview height is always 0 but I am not sure.  I am confident Phonegap and Admob is setup correctly as I can display ads if I use the CordovaWebView:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
       android:layout_above="@+id/adView" 
        android:id = "@+id/mainView"/>

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         ads:adUnitId="MYCODE"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"                        
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>    
</RelativeLayout >
```

Unfortunately due to this bug my localstorage is wiped out if I don't delay adding the adview as detailed here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements

In short can anyone provide working .java, main.xml for working with Phonegap, admob and local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write this code in the layout file:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="YOUR_ID"
    />
```

Comment: Hi Baba,  I added the addview within my LinearLayout but how do I reference it in my onCreate()??  This is what I have tried....       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
         AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView); but adView is null.  I checked the id and its available in the intellisense.  Maybe I am missing something to access my view in a DroidGap derived class

Comment: your code seems fine, no problem with it, just make sure to give the permission in the manifest file:  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

then declare the activity in the application tags:
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

everything should be fine

Comment: "everything should be fine" - but sadly its not. adView is null.  I have the correct permissions and my Manifest must be correct as the CordovaWebView implemenation above instantly works.  Why would adding mob in xml work when in code behind it does not?